Trying to access Synology NAS via DDNS Url, using HAproxy thru PFSense
I have 1) A new Synology Diskstation NAS, which gives me the ability to access my files on it remotely using a feature called Synology Drive, and 2) a PFSense box which serves as my home network's firewall/router.
I've already been able to successfully set up a VPN for my home network using a domain I purchased (we'll call it "mydomain.com") and a Dynamic Domain Name Service:  mydomain.com points to the public IP address of my PFSense box, and everything works, VPN-wise.  I was thinking I could use a subdomain ("NAS.mydomain.com") to point to my Synology NAS, so I could use its remote access features.
I read a couple of articles which advised not to just put the address to my Synology NAS out there in the domain record, for security reasons...and I'm not sure how I'd do that anyway, since it's behind the PFSense firewall and wouldn't have a public IP address of its own, in any case.  I read several articles on proxies stating that I could use a PFSense package like HAProxy to simply redirect any incoming requests for NAS.mydomain.com to my NAS' internal IP address.  However, I've been struggling on how to execute this.  HAProxy is proving to be very confusing (or, at least the instructions/guides I've found seem to be).  I was able to find this guide on how to do what I'm attempting...but after carrying out the steps, it still isn't working.  Can someone tell me what I may be doing wrong...or maybe if I'm going about this the wrong way and there's an easier way to accomplish this?  One article suggested that I could just simply port-forward...but it didn't provide any details, and I don't know how you could do that when the incoming request would be a URL, rather than an IP address.  Am I missing something?  THANKS in advance!
